# Understanding Preimage

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$.
The image of $\{−2, 3\}$ under $f$ is $f(\{−2, 3\}) = \{4, 9\}$, and the image of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I understand up till here. I cannot understand this statement -

"The preimage of $\{4, 9\}$ under $f$ is $f^{−1}(\{4, 9\}) = \{−3, −2, 2, 3\}$."

Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: The pre-image of $y$ is those values of $x$ that would lead to $x$. If you have multiple objects, you just put all their pre-images together. So, the pre-image of 4 is 2 and -2, and for 9 it's 3 and -3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: by definition, the preimage of $\{4\}$ is $f^{-1}(\{4\})=\left\{\,x \in \mathbb{R} \mid f(x) \in \{4\}\,\right\}$.

The above is equivalent to $x^2=4$, or $x=\pm 2$, so the preimage of $\{4\}$ is $f^{-1}(\{4\})=\{-2,2\}$.

Comment: Ohh! Gotchya! That was "stupid" category question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. And remember there's [no such thing as a stupid question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question) ;-)